# How do I clone an Ubuntu server under VMWare

Tags: ubuntu, vmware, clone

I have a Ubuntu 12.04 server running under VMWare. As best as I can tell, the VMWare vmbk file has been corrupted. The server is operating normally, but this is preventing backups (using Veeam). To remedy this, I'd like to create a duplicate VM without the corruption issue. However, with the corrupted file VMWare can't help me, e.g. create a simple clone. I can create a new VM. How do I clone the configuration / data from my problematic server into the new one?

Updated: just to clarify: I realise I can't use the VMWare clone tools. I will manually create a new VM (with a base OS if necessary).

How to I replicate the OS and data from one VM to another VM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a second disk of equal size to the first one and mount it onto the server.

One option is to get a similar install and use the good old cp-backup method (just copy /etc/ and anything else of interest) this means less downtime at the expense of data consistancy, since any files changed during backup won't be backed up.

Better yet, boot up a imaging livecd such as clonezilla and image disk to disk - this means more downtime, but is probably a much better option in terms of data consistancy.

Comment: I ended up creating a new VM with a fresh install of the OS. Then I copied the key files. Then I migrated webapps using whatever export/import feature they had, eg. svndump, phpmyadmin export, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The cloning option in VMware essentially takes a copy of the settings file and all the disks which are Vmdk files. So whatever issues you have just now would just be carried over in the clone.

Vmware player/workstation/etc all attempt to repair a machines disks every time its powered on. If you have not tried powering it off and and on I would try doing so, this may alow you to clone it after the repair...otherwise you may have a problem.

Bill